# Will Windows Repair ISO affect Linux partition

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

I am planning to run windows repair iso, to reinstall/repair windows(https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10ISO) on my laptop, which is dual booted(Windows and Ubuntu). Will this affect my Linux partition?

Comment: Will this affect my Linux partition? -- Though Windows don't know what ext4 is. But it is good at affecting EFI partition. So, you may have to install and fix EFI or boot partition.

Comment: If BIOS/MBR, it probably will not write any Linux logical partitions back into partition table. If not changing partitions as part of install backup partition table and write details of partition info so you have that to recreate missing entry easily. backup partition table before any changes, so you can get back to current if changes not correct
`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT_sda.txt`
So you know sectors:
`sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print`
 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition